# SKSpriteNode won't follow exact path

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

Issue is described in the image.

to 2: the SKSpriteNode should move again if the blocking node is removed

[image]

Comment: You should share your partial code showing your SKAction you are running on SKSpriteNode. Your problem could be related to physics-body, particularly how you configured mass/density off the nodes. However, If you want complete control over how the SKSpriteNode moves, you should consider implementing collisions so when SKSpriteNode and Blocking Node collides you can remove initial SKAction and apply new SKAction.

Comment: This won't solve the solution. I just want the answer how to create a SKAction that will move to a certain point if I give EXACT coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your objective in your comment:

If you need to move a node (`SKSpriteNode`, `SKShapeNode` etc.) to specific coordinate in your scene, here is your example:

```
let boxSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
var box = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 25, y: 25, width: boxSize.width, height: boxSize.height))
var point = CGPoint(x: 25, y: 125)
var animTime:TimeInterval = 2
box.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf: boxSize)

let moveToPointAction = SKAction.move(to: point, duration: animTime)
box.run(moveToPointAction)
```

Comment: @Lucas I give the answer to what you asked. You wanted to know how to create SKAction and move a object to specific point. My answer gives you exactly this. If you incorporate other object you need to implement collision detection and handle two objects as you like when they collide. Good luck